# How to boot MacBook Pro 2019 from a Linux USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, boot, mac, usb

I made a bootable USB flash drive (with Linux on it) using my ThinkPad. I can boot the ThinkPad using this USB flash drive.

Now I want to boot my MacBook Pro 2019 from this USB flash drive.

I went into the Secure Startup Utility on the Mac and allowed booting of unsigned operating systems and booting from external media, but when I reboot the MacBook holding down the Option key, I get a screen asking me what hard drive to boot from, and there is only one option: the Macintosh Hard Drive. The USB flash drive isn't shown!

How do I boot from the Linux USB flash drive on this MacBook Pro 2019?